Adding a Shapefile to a water mask made from a DEM file
I created a water mask from a DEM File. But there are no lakes and rivers on this water mask. I want to add some lakes and rivers to it. I tried to do this with Shapefile but I couldn't merge them. How can I do this?

Please edit your question to specify if the lakes and rivers are polygons, and if the water mask you created is raster or vector and is in the same CRS as the lakes and rivers shapefile,
